# What is the difference between a heredoc and process substitution?

Tags: here-document, process-substitution

In this answer, it is explained how to use a heredoc to interact with interactive programs by connecting their stdin with a heredoc.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130757/send-commands-to-socket-using-netcat

Since I thought "ah files!" I can use process substitution!

So I tried it with:

```
nc -lvkp 8000 <(echo "test")
```

And then I got the error:

```
Ncat: Could not resolve hostname "/dev/fd/63
```

So it is a file! But netcat doesn't understand it (it did understand it with a normal file that I wrote in `/tmp/commands.txt`). I don't mind so much that netcat doesn't understand it.

What I do mind is that I thought a heredoc also is a temporary file, if I understand it correctly. But apparently netcat understands that. So there must be a difference between this `/dev/fd/63` and a heredoc.

So what is the difference?

I think in part, there's something going on with `/dev/fd/63`. It's either not permanent, or the `dev/fd` part is different. And then I presume a heredoc does not get saved there, but somewhere else.

Edit: with `echo "test"`, I mean "print the word test".

Comment: did `netcat` "understand" `nc -lvkp 8000 /tmp/commands.txt`? what version of `netcat` is that?

Answer (score 3):

A here-document is a [standard redirection](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04), while process substitutions are not standard (and thus not all shells support them), nor are they redirections.

A process substitution explicitly *executes a command* to create output that may then be read from a particular pathname, while a here-document *creates a text file* that is immediately redirected.  A here-document *may* be implemented by writing to a temporary file, but it may also be implemented by writing to a named pipe or other similar thing.

Note that your `nc` invocation does not pass the result of the process substitution on the standard input stream of `nc`, but as a filename on the command line.  To pass the output of `echo` on standard input using a process substitution, use

```sh
nc -lvkp 8000 < <( echo "test" )
```

Notice how the first `<` redirects from the pathname that the process substitution results in.

With a here-document, you would have written

```sh
nc -lvkp 8000 <<'END'
test
END
```

Note how the redirection is done by the here-document, without reference to a particular pathname.  Also note how we don't use the `echo` command to create the text of the document that we redirect.

Answer (score 2):

A here-document is a redirection. The shell saves the text somewhere and then redirects that somewhere to the command's input. (This may not be the exact mechanism, but it's good enough for thinking about the system.)

A process substitution provides a path that connects to the input or output of the command *inside* the process substitution. However, it does not, by itself, apply any redirection to anything but that command. If the redirection symbols (`>` in `>(...)` or `<` in `<(...)`) make you think otherwise, just think that they apply to whatever's inside - `>`  pointing in to the process substitution applies to the *input* of the command within, `<` pointing out similarly applies to the output. They don't affect whatever's *outside*.

So, in:

```
nc 192.168.1.186 9760 <<END
command1
command2
END
```

`nc`'s input is redirected, but in

```
nc -lvkp 8000 <(echo "test")
```

`nc`'s input is **not** redirected. (`echo`'s output is piped to whatever will read from the process substitution, however.) `nc` just gets an extra argument.

You need to apply that redirection yourself:

```
nc -lvkp 8000 < <(echo "test")
```

Answer (score 2):

This highlights the difference. wc sees the same data in both cases. In the first, it gets an argument (a temporary filename) on the command line. In the second, the filename is eaten by the shell redirection, wc gets no arg, and it reads stdin by default.

```
Paul--) wc <( echo one two three )
      1       3      14 /dev/fd/63
Paul--) wc < <( echo one two three )
      1       3      14
Paul--)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have read some good answers, and they are not as simple as what I was going to write, so here goes:

- Here doc `<<`, connects to the standard in.
- Process substitution `<(...)`, connects to a "file", and then substitutes in the file-name.

Note: When we say file, we are using it in the Unix way. Not necessarily a file on disk. It could be a directory, named-pipe, anonymous-pipe, net-socket, unix-socket, ... In this case it will be a (de-anonymised: has a file-name, visible only to the processes that it is connected to) anonymous-pipe.

Comment: Different answers with different forms of simplicity make understanding things easier. So IMO it's helpful.